# Multiple Version Resources

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am writing several C++ libraries inside of visual studio. I know I can use the Version Resource to assign DLL's a version, product name, and so on but is there a way that I can swap out different Resource scripts depending on my configuration settings. For instance, say I am compiling for x86 I want the product name to be x86, likewise for x64 I want the product name to be x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#ifdef`s in resource files. But using `#ifdef`s directly in he resource files, can sometimes screw with the IDE's resource editor (it has happened for me in Visual Studio 2008). I would therefore create two resource files (e.g. resource-x86.rc and resource-x64.rc) and include them in the main rc file like this:

```
#ifdef X86
#include "resource-x86.rc"
#elif X64
#include "resource-x64.rc"
#else
#error Unsupported platform!
#endif
```

Comment: We use #define for things like Product Name, etc, and it works fine for us.  Granted we don't change these between configurations, but I don't see any reason why you couldn't.

Comment: I ended up modifying the RC with #ifdefs. Since the file won't be changed very often I figured it was a simpler solution. Visual Studio doesn't seem to complain. One thing I had to do, obviously, was add Preprocessor Definitions to the Resource section of the project properties, after that everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

copied from [here](http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/conditional-compilation-of-resource.html)

--

1. Open your project in Visual Studio
2. Right click on resource script file (e.g. app.rc) and select "Properties"
3. At the top of the property page, select one platform like "Win32" or "x64".
4. In the left menu bar, select [Configuration Properties] / [Resources] / [General].
5. In the "Preprocessor Definitions" field, add "WIN32" for "Win32" platform and "WIN64" for "x64" platform. The field value will become "WINXX;_UNICODE;UNICODE". (XX will be 32 or 64)
6. Click OK to close the window.
7. Right click on resource script file (e.g. app.rc) and select "View Code".
8. In the code editor, add #ifdef and #elif to conditionally include resources when compiling. Use "WIN32" and "WIN64" preprocessor definitions that we defined just now.

Here is a sample code:

```
--------------------------------
#ifdef WIN32
   IDB_BITMAP1             BITMAP                  "bitmap1.bmp"
   IDB_BITMAP2             BITMAP                  "bitmap2.bmp"
#elif WIN64
   IDR_TOOLBAR1            BITMAP                  "toolbar1.bmp"
   IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "icon1.ico"
#endif
--------------------------------
```

9. Save the resource script file and compile the project in different platforms.